# Running Jupyter from Docker Session Fails

Tags: python, docker, jupyter, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-docker

I have a docker container that completes successfully and is in proper working order. I can see that jupyter, python3 install successfully. Other than the user-friendly interface Jupyter provides, the docker is working as expected.

I have already tried running this code within the image build and receive the same result.

Other Google searches for this have only shown people using Cloudera/Anaconda. I am using neither.

```
me@gpu:which python3 
/usr/bin/python3

me@gpu:which jupyter 
/usr/local/bin/jupyter

me@gpu:jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --allow-root
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
```

I expect to be able to access a jupyter notebook via localhost:8888.